# How to update_attributes from json with ease

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have this model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to address_type
  attr_accessible :text
end
```

And another model which holds the type like so:

```
class AddressType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many addresses
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

And in this model there are three types:

```
name => residential
name => po_box
name => government
```

Now, lets say I have this incoming JSON:

```
{
    text: "some text here",
    address_type: "po_box"
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this in the controller that accepts the JSON without having to find the `address_type` object first:

```
address = Address.new
address.update_attributes(params)
```

I found [this gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) but it seems to be design to work on JSON output only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving JSON in the params hash you can convert it via:

```
data = JSON.parse(params[:name_of_the_JSON_fields])
address = Address.new
address.update_attributes(data)
```